# Can we access the URL of next request of browser in prevailing HTML page 's unload function 

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

As Html code resides until new url request's response doesn't come .Then Browser calls BeforeUnload and Unload function.

This means anywhere in the browser, the url is residing which has been hit for unloading the current one. So is there any way we can get that (new) URL in the Unload function?

Actually My scenario is that I want pop up to be opened for providing the other options when user has just hit another URL which doesn't resemble to our domain , showing that he want to go out from our site.

Comment: No, it's not possible to read the location of the next document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - you don't have access to this.  What you *can* do is trap the click event for all elements that would cause you to leave the page and then store the URL of them in a global variable.  You would then have that value available "beforeunload".

This will obviously only work with elements on your page.  If the user types a URL into the address bar then there is nothing you can do to capture that.

Comment: If you make the `unload` code use a value which is changed by elements which **don't** make the user leave, then it will also catch address-bar exits (though it won't give the URL)

Comment: You've lost me - why would you change the value with elements that don't make the user leave?

Comment: This way, you know when NOT to display the popup, and you assume that every other action SHOULD display the popup - this will include when a user closes the window, types an address into the URL bar, etc.

Comment: Okay, I can see what you're getting at now, but he's asking how to get the URL of where you're going to.  He can easily always use the beforeunload method to trap leaving the page, without having to tie any events to controls that don't cause leaving the page.

Comment: I was responding more to the last part of his question, which is that he doesn't explicitly need the URL, he just needs to know if they're leaving his domain.

Answer (score 1):

No, that would be a serious security leak.

You can attach an event handler to your forms and links so you can tell if the user is leaving the page by using one of them. You can't tell if the user is going to another page on your site via a bookmark, typing the URL, clicking back, etc though.

Answer (score 0):

Make a global JS value something like
`var supressPopup = false;`

Then, make all of your external links also include a method which sets this boolean to `true` (ie `javascript:supressPopup=true;location.href='newurl.html'` (This is an ugly way to do it, but just an example- you could use a script which scans all of the page's `<a>` tags and adds an onClick event if the `href` doesn't start with `http`)

Then, in your `unload` code, check for `supressPopup`; if it is false, show your popup.

Comment: This won't give the URL of the external document, but it will tell you *if* it's *not* an external document.